# $\mathrm{rank}(A)+\mathrm{rank}(I-A)=n$ for $A$ idempotent matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank, idempotents

> Let $A$ be a square matrix of order $n$. Prove that if $A^2=A$ then $\mathrm{rank}(A)+\mathrm{rank}(I-A)=n$.

I tried to bring the $A$ over to the left hand side and factorise it out, but do not know how to proceed. please help.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**. Show that under the given condition, the following holds:

$$\ker A = \operatorname{im} (I -A) $$

Comment: i havent learn about kernel yet

Answer (score 0):

Let rank $(A) = r$ and $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $A$. Since $A$ is idempotent then
\begin{align*}
\lambda x = A x = A^2 x = A.Ax = A\lambda x = \lambda Ax = \lambda^2 x
\end{align*}
meaning that $\lambda =0$ or $1$. So the eigenvalues of $A$ are either $0$ or $1$. Writing the eigenvalue decomposition of $A$ as
\begin{align*}
A = U^T \Lambda U
\end{align*}
where $U$ is the orthogonal matrix of eigenvectors of $A$ and $\Lambda$ is the diagonal matrix of eigenvalues of $A$, we get
\begin{align*}
I- A &= I - U^T \Lambda U\\
&= U^TU - U^T \Lambda U\\
&= U^T(I-\Lambda)U.
\end{align*}
Note that since rank $(A) = r$ then only $r$ of the elements of the diagonal of $\Lambda$ are $1$ and the rest are zero. This implies that only $n-r$ elements of $I-\Lambda$ are $1$ and the rest are zero. So, rank $(I-A) = n-r$ and you have the desired result.